# how does dataset run at compile time, when Apache spark has lazy evaluation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I can see that Dataset will tell you if the column exists or not during compile time.
If Spark has lazy evaluation,
How can it get the schema of the data before we run the action command in runtime.

Let me know if my above understanding is wrong.

Comment: How can the compiler tells you that a column doesn't exist a compile time? I never saw that. Can you put an image or some compilation logs?

Comment: I have read it in the link  
https://blog.knoldus.com/spark-type-safety-in-dataset-vs-dataframe/

Querying on non-existing columns

Comment: _<console>:25: error: value salary is not a member of Employ_: The normal underlying _Java_ compiler finds that `salary` isn't a member of the object `Employ` your are telling using

Comment: So the java complier can read the file, then its against lazy evaluation right, please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: The compiler only see the statement `map(employ => employ.salary)` that it shall compile in order to execute it,  __later__, lazily, but it can't, because there's an error on it : `salary` isn't a member of the class `Employ` that the compiler knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between runtime and compile time.  Runtime is lazy evaluation.  (Spark doesn't fill the data into the designed classes until it has to.)

At compile time because of the strong typing spark can detect if the data matches the classes that you have provided that "must" match the columns.  This does not stop you from entering "string SQL" that could end up with runtime errors.  (This is in fact why "String SQL" is discouraged and programmatic access of datasets is encouraged.)

An [example](https://databricks.com/spark/getting-started-with-apache-spark/datasets) of a typical way you might create a dataset:

```
case class Person (name: String, age: Long)
val ds = spark.read.json("/databricks-datasets/samples/people/people.json").as[Person]
```

`ds` in the sample above doesn't appear strongly typed but it is.  You must interact with `ds` as if it was a `Person` Dataset.  The compiler can ensure that you do, and enforce coding practices that make you compliant with the Person Class.  A weakly typed language could not do that because it would not be able to infer the type. Scala/Spark appears weakly typed because it uses a lot of inferences, but those inferences are strongly enforced.

Comment: So Matt, you are saying that although its lazy evaluation, the compiler can still read the file and know the columns, 
could you please elaborate.
- My understanding of strong type is that you cannot cast the data from one variable to another. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Updated my answer.  Strongly typed means that every variable has only one type.  Weak typing means every variable could be any type depending on the current context. (Strongly typed variables are the only langauges that require casting.  Weakly typed variables wouldn't require type casting.)

Comment: scala/spark looks weekly typed because of the use of "val" and "var" but it actually gets bound at compile time through what is put into it.  Once initialize it's stongly typed.  It's just a nice bit of syntax that you don't have to declare the variable type in advance. (Like you do in Java)

Comment: If you found my answer helpful please upvote it.  If you think it's the answer and your comfortable, please mark it as the correct answer.